# google closure compiler && audio event

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

i have folowing code:
(without compilation everything work fine)

```
var audio = new Audio("audio.ogg");
goog.events.listen(audio, 'timeupdate', function(e){
```

ERROR

```
actual parameter 1 of goog.events.listen does not match formal parameter
>> found   : Audio
>> required: (EventTarget|goog.events.Listenable|null)
>> goog.events.listen(this.audio.singing, 'timeupdate', function(e){
```

my Extern

```
/**
 * @param {string=} src
 * @constructor
 */
var Audio = function(src) {};
Audio.prototype.play = function() {};
```

How can i compile with internal event like this?
Thank you

Comment: Where is the actual definition of `Audio`? You need to provide the proper type information, but I need to see the definition to provide that.

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly try augmenting your extern definition:

```
goog.require('goog.events.EventTarget');
/**
 * @param {string=} src
 * @constructor
 * @extends {EventTarget}
 */
var Audio = function(src) {};
Audio.prototype.play = function() {};
```

## Edit:

So it turns out that your problem had been addressed in the Closure Compiler codebase and then that fix was reverted. See [**the changelog here**](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/detail?r=6ada994d101c).

The relevant part of that commit I reproduce below:

```
/**
* @param {string=} src address of the media resource (a URL)
* @constructor
* @extends {HTMLAudioElement}
* @see http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#the-audio-element
*/
var Audio = function(src) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Closure compiler provides externs which should be added to externs list

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Externs-For-Common-Libraries

The one with Audio API is called html5 or something like that